# Turn on LED using pi4j and Raspberry pi 4

Tags: led, java, pi4j

I am so new to Raspberry Pi. I want to use pi4j 2 to flash a led that is connected to a raspberry pi. This is my code but the led does not turn on at all:

```
import com.pi4j.Pi4J;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.digital.DigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.digital.DigitalState;

public class RobotResource {
private static final int PIN_LED = 16;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    var pi4j = Pi4J.newAutoContext();
    int x = 0;

    var ledConfig = DigitalOutput.newConfigBuilder(pi4j)
            .id("led")
            .name("LED Flasher")
            .address(PIN_LED)
            .shutdown(DigitalState.LOW)
            .initial(DigitalState.LOW)
            .provider("pigpio-digital-output");

    var led = pi4j.create(ledConfig);


    while (x != 5) {

        led.high();
        sleep(1000);
        led.low();
        sleep(500);
        x++;
    }
}

static void sleep(int z) {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(z);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Thread.sleep");
    }
}
}
```

What should I do to turn on the led?

Thanks in advance for your guide.

Comment: Which tutorial are your reading? Perhaps try this one: (1) The Pi4J Project v1.2 - 2019-03-05
https://pi4j.com/1.2/index.html

(2) Simple GPIO Control using Pi4J - The following example demonstrates the simple control of a GPIO pin on the Raspberry Pi
https://pi4j.com/1.2/example/control.html

Comment: @tlfong01 I found the code in the StackOverflow. I cant use pi4j v1.2. must use pi4j v2.0.

Comment: Try the following. `sudo pigpiod` then `pigs w 16 1` then `pigs w 16 0`.  Does the LED go on then off?  If not check you have connected it to GPIO 16 (NOT pin 16) and that it is connected the right way around.  https://pinout.xyz/